# Empty screen at booting after upgrade to Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: boot, lenovo

I upgraded from Ubuntu 20 to 21.04 and booting fails totally on my Lenovo X1 Carbon laptop. BIOS does not pass further than recognizing hardware (HDD and flash drive) and then the screen turns empty. I tried booting from a flash drive - it failed the same way as booting from HDD. There is no info about a bootsector or an attempt to load the system. I would truly appreciate your help as I am clueless!

Comment: There is no Ubuntu version 20, so what did you upgrade from? What do you mean by booting fails? By empty screen do you mean a black screen?

Comment: Ubuntu Core 20 is a very different system to the *deb* based 21.04 (the 20 or *year* format has been used to highlight *snap* only products since 2016, so they are distinguished from the more common *deb* based *year.month* products). Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (if that's what you mean) was QA-tested to upgrade to the next release (ie. 20.10) and will also be QA-tested in the future for upgrades to the next LTS release (ie. prior to the release of 22.04.1) so for best results stick to fully QA-tested *release-upgrade* paths.

Comment: Hi David, I had xubuntu 20.10 installed and a couple days ago I was asked by the system installer to upgrade to ubuntu 21.04, as far as I remember. The installation went  smoothly but after a reboot I'm just getting a black screen after the hardware check. I don't think I can attach a picture here but this is just a hardware check by BIOS, I believe. It checks CPU,  then it says: System BIOS shadowed, Video BIOS shadowed, BIOS Version, Fixed DIsk: SAMSUNG and Press <F1> to BIOS Setup.  Then the screen turns black and that's it. Frozen. Any ideas?